# Spring Insight Operations - error when deploying Insight Agent on Jboss 5.1.2

Tags: spring, spring-insight

I am trying to get Spring insight working to troubleshoot performance issues with an application that is deployed on Jboss EAP 5.1.2. If I understand correctly, the developer edition of spring insight works only on tomcat server. As I would have to create resources and spend time resolving dependency/class loading issues with deploying my app on tomcat server, I decided to try out "Insight Operations" 1.8.3 (trial version from vmware).

I have the dashboard up and running. I downloaded the insight-agent.jar from the dashboard (from Administrations tab). I was able to install the agent successfully using this command:

```
    java -jar insight-agent.jar --install --jboss_profile test
```

The above command tried to deploy insight-agent.war file to my jboss profile, but there are issues with the deployment:

Can you please help?

> 2012-11-21 12:56:34,028 INFO  [org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl] (main) JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.2 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_2 date=201111102209)] Started in 39s:513ms
>   2012-11-21 12:57:48,904 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] (HDScanner) deploy, ctxPath=/insight-agent
>   2012-11-21 12:57:49,042 SEVERE [com.springsource.insight.classpath.InsightClassPathMunger] (HDScanner) Context not initialized by an InsightClassLoader
>   2012-11-21 12:57:49,043 SEVERE [com.springsource.insight.classpath.InsightClassPathMunger] (HDScanner) Thus, I am not able to add conf or plugins to the classpath
>   2012-11-21 12:57:49,043 SEVERE [com.springsource.insight.classpath.InsightClassPathMunger] (HDScanner) I will, however, try to configure the logging subsystem
>   2012-11-21 12:57:49,051 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/insight-agent]] (HDScanner) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
>   2012-11-21 12:57:49,514 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (HDScanner) Context initialization failed
>   **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical**
>       at java.io.File.(File.java:363)
>       at org.jboss.net.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.(FileURLConnection.java:62)
>       at org.jboss.net.protocol.file.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:40)
>       at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:945)
>       at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:121)
>       at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:181)
>       at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:161)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:663)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:638)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:407)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4389)
>       at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:313)
>       at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145)
>       at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
>       at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:122)
>       at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>       at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
>       at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
>       at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
>       at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
>       at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>       at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:297)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
>       at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
>       at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
>       at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
>       at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
>       at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
>       at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
>       at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193)
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
>       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
>       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:409)
>       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:294)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Answer (score 0):

This is JBoss EAP 5.1 (aka v5.1.2) issue [JBPAPP-8065](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPAPP-8065).